# How do I get Ubuntu to forget about a destroyed zfs pool?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, zfs, zfsonlinux

I have also asked this question over on Ask Ubuntu but I thought I'd try here as well. The details can be found at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/304822/how-do-i-get-ubuntu-to-forget-all-about-an-old-zpool

I just can't get Ubuntu to forget about the old zpool. The impact is that it always loads this pool when the system boots: even though it was destroyed and the disks removed.

Gareth

Comment: OK, question answered. Because I was running with a ZFS root, I needed to update the initial RAMFS as well.

Comment: Note that you can answer your own question, which is actually encouraged.  A clear, detailed, well written answer will help people to find this answer as a solution to a similar problem in the future.  And I think this is actually a pretty common problem or point of confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is old, but I want to close it off.
The answer was that the pool couldn't be destroyed because it was the root pool. Once I had updated the initial RAMFS to make use of a different pool, I could then destroy the old one.